# Use hook form alter to change input type

Tags: ubercart, forms

I am trying to change the input type on an ubercart checkout form using `hook_form_alter`. I added an extra field using the uc cart extra fields pane module but there is no option to add e-mail - only text - and I need the field I added to validate as an e-mail.

The field in question is:

```
<input type="text" id="edit-panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-bill-to-email" name="panes[billing][address][billing_ucxf_bill_to_email]" value="" size="32" maxlength="255" class="form-text required">
```

The code I am using but with no success is:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'uc-cart-checkout-form') {
    form['panes-billing-address-billing-ucxf-bill-to-email'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['type'] = 'email';
  }
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want alter a form via an ID check you should be using `$form_id == 'uc_cart_checkout_form'`. Drupal form generation functions don't use "-" characters like generated CSS id/class attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that. Unfortunately I now get an error `Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/content/g/l/o/.../sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_store/includes/uc_ajax_attach.inc on line 108`.